# Убрать гласные буквы в строке и слова которые одинаковые с последним словом

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня код уже удаляет гласные и теперь нужно только удалить слова путь.

```
s = 'неделя, человек, путь, женщина, книга, путь, глаз, сторона, дом, путь.'
s = s.replace('а', '')
s = s.replace('у', '')
s = s.replace('о', '')
s = s.replace('ы', '')
s = s.replace('и', '')
s = s.replace('э', '')
s = s.replace('я', '')
s = s.replace('ю', '')
s = s.replace('ё', '')
s = s.replace('е', '')
x = s.split()[-1]
s = s.replace(x, "")
print(s)
```

У меня код уже удаляет гласные и теперь нужно только удалить слова путь. Щас х = "путь." и я не могу удалить другие повторяющиеся слова, потому что они "путь,". Как мне удалить все повторяющиеся слова?

Comment: вы же вчера задавали вопрос про удаление слов, которые равны первому слову
что изменилось? тот же алгоритм по сути

Comment: это другая задача, я немного изменил эту задачу и сделал такой же алгоритм только с последним словом, но здесь последний элемент считается "путь."

Comment: но ведь в итоге задача стала ровно такой же и решается так же, разве нет?

Comment: нет, потому что после последнего слова точка, а после других слов запятая. Если после каждого слова будет точка тогда задача решается моим алгоритмом

Comment: отрезаем точку и все - та же задача, я про то, что скрестить задачи, вернее решения уже несложно

Comment: как отрезать только точку?

Comment: `text = text[:-1]` - убираем последний символ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 'неделя, человек, путь, женщина, книга, путь, глаз, сторона, дом, путь.'
s = s.replace('а', '')
s = s.replace('у', '')
s = s.replace('о', '')
s = s.replace('ы', '')
s = s.replace('и', '')
s = s.replace('э', '')
s = s.replace('я', '')
s = s.replace('ю', '')
s = s.replace('ё', '')
s = s.replace('е', '')
s = s[:-1]
x = s.split()[-1]
s = s.replace(x, '').replace(', ,', ',')
s = s[:-2]
print(s + '.')
```

Answer (score 1):

убрать гласные и удалить последнюю букву можно и так:

```
s = 'неделя, человек, путь, женщина, книга, путь, глаз, сторона, дом, путь.'

s = ''.join(letter for letter in s if letter not in 'аеёиоуыэюя')[:-1]

print(s)
```

гораздо короче

а убрать слово потом можно и так:

```
words = s.split(", ")

s = ', '.join(word for word in words if word != words[-1])
```

Comment: что значит запятая в split?

Comment: в первом примере мне не надо удалять последнюю букву

Comment: использовал `", "` как разделитель

Comment: я опубликовал свое решение, можете посмотреть, спасибо вам за помощь :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import string

VOWELS = "ауоыиэяюёе"

s = 'неделя, человек, путь, женщина, книга, путь, глаз, сторона, дом, путь.'

trans_table = str.maketrans("", "", VOWELS + string.punctuation)    
without_wowels_and_punct = s.translate(trans_table)

wordlist = without_wowels_and_punct.split()
last_word = wordlist[-1]

wordlist = [word for word in wordlist if word != last_word]    
result = ", ".join(wordlist) + "."
```

---

Объяснение:

1. Удаление всех желаемых символов возможно сделать сразу применением метода `.translate()` на строку `s`.

   - Для того приготовим нужную таблицу (словарь) `trans_table` всех символов, которые мы хотим удалить - в том числе *и все символы пунктуации.*
   - Такой словарь, чтобы его возможно было задать как аргумент метода `.translate()`, нужен иметь как ключи не буквы, а их *Юникод ординальные числа.*

     Для создания такого словаря — со всеми значениями `None` (т.е. «удалить»)   - применим метод `.maketrans()`. Первые 2 параметра нас не интересуют (что чем заменить), только 3-ий (что удалить):

     ```
     >>> trans_table = str.maketrans("", "", VOWELS + string.punctuation)

     {1072: None,      # а
      1091: None,      # у
      1086: None,      # о
      1099: None,      # ы
      1080: None,      # и
      1101: None,      # э
      1103: None,      # я
      1102: None,      # ю
      1105: None,      # ё
      1077: None,      # е
        33: None,      # !
        34: None,      # "
        35: None,      # #
           ...
           ...
       124: None,      # |
       125: None,      # }
       126: None}      # ~
     ```
2. После удаления всех ненужных символов из строки применением метода `.translate()`:

   ```
   >>>s.translate(trans_table)

   'ндл члвк пть жнщн кнг пть глз стрн дм пть'
   ```

   - создаем из него *список слов*:

     ```
     >>> without_wowels_and_punct.split()

     ['ндл', 'члвк', 'пть', 'жнщн', 'кнг', 'пть', 'глз', 'стрн', 'дм', 'пть']
     ```
   - выберем из него последнее: `last_word = wordlist[-1]` (оно уже без пунктуации)
   - и использованием генератора списка удалим все его появления из этого списка:

     ```
     wordlist = [word  for word in wordlist  if word != last_word]
     ```

     получая в переменной `wordlist` список

     ```
     >>> wordlist

     ['ндл', 'члвк', 'жнщн', 'кнг', 'глз', 'стрн', 'дм']
     ```
3. Наконец из списка сделаем опять строку применением метода `.join()` на строку `", "` (которой мы хотим отделить отдельные слова — элементы списка) и добавим заключительную точку (`.`):

   ```
   >>> ", ".join(wordlist) + "."

   'ндл, члвк, жнщн, кнг, глз, стрн, дм.'
   ```